# Usar Ajax na navegação de todo o site tem algum problema?

Tags: javascript, jquery

É porque o site teria uma Web Rádio, e eu não quero que atualize a cada troca de página, pois isso para a reprodução. Gostaria de saber se há problema em fazer a paginação em Ajax?

E outra: Ajax interfere no Adsense?

Obrigado e boa noite à todos.

Comment: Apenas requisições síncronas param a reprodução da página, nesse caso você quis dizer JAX (JavaScript and XML)?

Answer (score 0):

A pergunta pode estar errada no primeiro ponto: *"eu não quero que atualize a cada troca de página, pois isso para a reprodução"*, a página continua executando se a requisição HTTP que estiver sendo feita é assíncrona, e como diz na pergunta, "A.J.A.X" (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML).

O problema é usar requisições HTTP de AJAX para fazer simulações de chat, jogos, etc., nesse caso você poderia precisar de suporte no seu servidor para usar sockets (ou [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/WebSocket)s). Também há técnicas como o [Long Polling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/333664) para minimalizar o uso do seu servidor por causa de requisições HTTP.

---

Até agora, pelo que sei sobre algumas regras do Adsense, se os anúncios da página forem removidos, poderia haver alguma interferência, mas isso não seria causa do AJAX, talvez pela navegação que modifica a página HTML.

Você pode reservar o que pertence ao Adsense em containers, e evitar a re-generação/modificação desses containers enquanto a navegação do AJAX ocorre.